# Java - Netty splitting message bytes

Tags: java, byte, netty

I'm trying to send a message from client to server with Netty 3.

The message consists of:

400 Strings
210 Integers

Message average bytes: 3400

The message is being sent successfully by the client, the problem is on the server, which is splitting the bytes.

```
Client: sent 3400 bytes.    
Server: received 1024 bytes.
Server: received 2048 bytes.
Server: received 328 bytes.
```

Encoding:

```
public void sendFriendList(final Player player) {
    final int friendsSize = player.getFriendsIgnores().getFriends().size();
        final OutputStream stream = new OutputStream(12500);
        stream.writeSmart(83); //packet ID
        stream.writeShort(friendsSize); //number of friends
        stream.writeInt(player.getPlayerDefinition().index()); //player id
        for (int id : player.getFriendsIgnores().getFriends()) { //array of integers
            stream.writeInt(id);
            stream.writeString(PlayerLoader.getUsername(id));
            stream.writeString(PlayerLoader.getDisplayName(id));
            stream.writeInt(PlayerLoader.getWorld(id));
        }
        session.write(stream);
    }
```

Decoding:

```
case 83:
        int friendsSize = stream.readUnsignedShort();
        int playerId = stream.readInt();
        player = World.get(playerId);

        if (player != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < friendsSize; i++) {
            int id = stream.readInt();
            username = stream.readString();
            displayName = stream.readString();
            world = stream.readInt();
            player.getFriendsIgnores().addFriendDetails(id, username, displayName, world);
            }
        }
        break;
```

Comment: What is the question Tom?

Comment: How do i get the full bytes in a single message instead of 3 messages with split bytes?